# How do I make a QWidget automatically scale vertically to it's contents?

Tags: c++, qt

I've made a QT Designer Form called DropDownMenu. Essentially it is just a QWidget with a QVBoxLayout inside of it.

DropDownMenu has a function that pragmatically adds buttons to it.

```
QPushButton* DropDownMenu::AddButton(
        const QString& text)
{
    QPushButton* new_button = new QPushButton(text, this);
    m_ui->LayoutManager->addWidget(new_button);

    return new_button;
}
```

I then add a QWidget to my MainWindow inside of QT Designer & promote this widget to DropDownMenu. Then I add buttons to this new QWidget using the AddButton function.

The end result looks like this...

[image: https://i.imgur.com/KCbaZJi.png]

I want to make it so the containers scale according to how many buttons or widgets are placed inside of the layout, but they seem to just get squeezed together so that they fit the parents default size.

How can I make it so the parent scales to the size of all it's children?

Comment: `DropDownMenu` sounds a custom widget ... whats is `LayoutManager` ?  looks you didn't share [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: As I said in the first 2 sentences... DropDownMenu is a basic QT Designer Form (QWidget and Layoutmanager is QVBoxLayout).

Comment: @Rick 
you could share the .ui file

Comment: new_button should have `minimalSize` maybe? Or/and something else about `sizeHint`? That would stretch the container widget unless it was put in some layout itself, or given maximum size so that it shrinks.